# In ASP.Net Web API, how do you fake PUT and DELETE?

Tags: rest, asp.net-web-api, http-delete, http-put

I'm experimenting with ASP.Net Web API, which, by convention, splits controller methods into a Restful style of Get(), Put, Post and Delete. My question is how does one handle the PUT and DELETE requests that might come from a non-Ajax browser request.

So, let's say that I have foobar with id = 123. A normal fetch request would be

```
/foobars/123
```

To delete the item, the Restful way would be to issue:

```
DELETE /foobars/123
```

However, `PUT` and `DELETE` are not browser standards and do not have enough major browser support to be trusted if your request is coming from a non-Ajax browser request. So a common accepted workaround is:

```
POST /foobars/123?_method=DELETE (source: Restful Web Services)
```

For the new ASP.Net Web API, is there a best practice / common approach for working with this problem? What I want is for anything with a `_method=DELETE` to be routed to the `DELETE()` method in the controller and `_method=PUT` to be routed to the PUT() method of a controller.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can easily achieve this using a `DelegatingHandler`.

So you would code:

```
public class HttpMethodHandler : DelegatingHandler
{
    protected override Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        var queryString = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(request.RequestUri.Query);
        if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(queryString["_method"]))
        {
            request.Method = new HttpMethod(queryString["_method"]);
        }
        return base.SendAsync(request, cancellationToken);
    }
}
```

And then add the handler to the pipeline. I have a [blog](http://byterot.blogspot.co.uk/2012/05/aspnet-web-api-series-messagehandler.html) on that.

Comment: Aliostad makes a good point. This should not be the accepted answer because it introduces a dangerous security vulnerability. Someone could send a (non-technical) user the link `"/delete/thing/23?_method=delete"` and they would unwittingly delete "thing 23" without ever making the choice to do so.

The correct answer would be to use "Request.Form["_method"]", which would ensure the parameter can only be passed as a POST request rather than a GET queryparam.